# jaxb bindigs - marshaling part of XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a XML file read by jaxb and I would like to ask if there is a way how to marshall part of XML back. Not all xml, but only some element with subelements. Maybe implementing toString method in jaxb classes? Any other ideas how to get piece of original Xml back? thanks for any hints.

Comment: The answer there is NOT the answer to this question. Please reopen. This question is about marshalling, the other one is about unmarshalling with a completely different focus.

Comment: I guess the OP just needs `marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement(new QName("subElementName"), SubElementType.class, subElementValue), System.out);`